# NetBeans Error Ambiguous on Method contains(Object)

Tags: java, netbeans, ambiguous

Can anybody help me to fix this error in NetBeans 8.0.2 ? I am using Java 1.7 on Mac. This error did not occurred in Eclipse. Netbeans always tell me that the method `contains(Object)` ambiguous within `Collection` or `List`, whereas I am using `ArrayList` in my method.

```
reference to contains is ambiguous
  both method contains(Object) in Collection and method contains(Object) in List match
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

[image: Screenhost error on NetBeans 8.0.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's... just... weird.  `List` inherits from `Collection` and overrides the `contains(Object)` method, which is implemented in `ArrayList`.  This works fine in Eclipse.

Looks like a serious bug in NetBeans to me.

I recommend reinstalling NetBeans from scratch to see if that fixes the problem.